# Connect remotely using Ubuntu to Win7 from outside local network

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, ubuntu-16.04, remmina

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and when I travel, I want to connect it to a Win7 laptop on my local network at home, using Remmina. I have successfully made the connection while both machines are on the same network but I'm trying to figure out how to set up connecting from outside my local network, which is using a Linksys EA6100 wifi router.

Comment: You need to look into "port forwarding".

Answer (score 0):

You could setup RealVNC Server on the PC and login with an account and use RealVNC Viewer on the  Linux machine and login to that

***OR***

[Setup a VPN](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-18-04) and port forward it

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using VPN to enter your local network. From your local network, everything should work as usual.